# Redirect to /downloadable/customer/products after successful checkout automatically | Magento 2.4.1 CE

Tags: products, redirect, downloadable, magento2.4.1

Cause we only sell downloadable products in our Magento 2.4.1 CE with Autoinvoice we would like to redirect our costumers automatically to the /downloadable/customer/products/ instead of the /checkout/onepage/success/ page. Is there any solution? Thank you!

Comment: simple solution without code is in the url rewrite manager set a custom 301 from checkout/onepage/success/ to the new location. if you want a more technical way to implement then you will need to overwrite the checkout success controller

Comment: Thank you Dava! We use the url rewrite even though it isn't the best solution for pay per advanced payment ;-)

Comment: Id need more information as to the conditions of the redirect if you were going to overwrite the controller :)